# How do I find the altitude, base and the length of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

The base of an Isosceles triangle is $5\text{ cm}$ longer than the height. If the area of the triangle is $12\text{ cm}^2$. Find the height, base and the length of one of its equal sides.

Comment: Do you know a formula for the area of a triangle in terms of its base and height? Do you know how to turn sentences into equations?

Comment: Let the sides of the triangle be $a, a, 2b$.  What can you make of the conditions given?

Answer (score 0):

Since, the area is given as 12, and area of a triangle is given by $$\frac{1}{2}\times \text{base}\times \text{height}=12$$

Now, you are also given that $$\text{base}=\text{height}+5$$

So, Use the second information into the formula, generate an equation and solve it!

HINT: $\text{height}=1 \text{cm}$
$\text{base}= 6 \text{cm}$

Comment: I got the quadratic equation in h as $h^2+5h-24=0$, the solution is 1. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Maybe a pen an paper will help :)

Comment: Yes! You are right! I was fixed on a basis shorter than height, not longer as asked from the OP :(  ........I deleted all.

Answer (score 0):

The equation h^2 +5h -24 = 0 is correct. Factoring by inspection: (h+8)(h-3)=0. 
The height is 3 cm. bh/2=12, b=8 cm. The isoceles triangle is made of a pair of 3-4-5 ratio right triangles. The equal sides are 10 cm.

Comment: The equal sides are 5 cm. Since time has passed and no chance of doing someone's homework, I reworked your answer with the details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a math "word problem". You express the statements mathematically and then use math facts to get a solution.

$B=H+5$

Using the formula for the area of a triangle,

$.5BH=.5(H+5)H=.5(H^2+5H)=12$

Multiplying by 2 we get a quadratic equation,

$h^2 +5h -24 = 0$

Factoring by inspection: $(h+8)(h-3)=0$. The height is 3 cm. and the base is 8 cm.

Since we are dealing with an isosceles triangle, the height can be viewed as the perpendicular bisector of the base. Using Pythagorean's Theorem, you can see that the two equal sides have a length of 5 cm.